# $\mathcal{N}=1$ SUSY gauge theories in 2D?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-invariance

The following introduction explains what I mean by $\mathcal{N}=1$ (often also called (1,1)) supersymmetry in 2D.

We can define a superfield
$$\Phi(x,\theta)=\phi(x)+\bar{\theta}\psi +\frac{1}{2}\bar{\theta}{\theta} F$$
where both $\theta, \psi$ are Majorana. Bars denote $\bar{\theta}_\beta =\theta_\alpha\gamma^0_{\alpha\beta}$

We can define a superderivative
$$\mathcal{D}_\alpha=\bar{\partial}_\alpha-i(\gamma^\mu\theta)_\alpha\partial_\mu$$
where $\partial_\alpha$ is the derivative with respect to $\theta_\alpha$.

Then we can construct a kinetic term like
$$\int d\theta d\bar{\theta}\frac{1}{2}\bar{\mathcal{D}}\Phi\mathcal{D}\Phi=\frac{1}{2}\left[(\partial \phi)^2+i\bar{\psi}\gamma \partial \psi +F^2\right]$$

---

Now suppose I want to give $\phi^i$ and $\psi^i$ indices so that they transform under some internal symmetry group. How do I construct a supersymmetric Lagrangian in terms of superfields like $\Phi^i$ which is gauge invariant under this internal symmetry?

In 4D and also for extended $(2,2)$ SUSY in 2D we have some Lagrangian schematically like
$$\int d^4\theta \bar{\Phi}e^V \Phi$$
where we have extra $\theta$ in our superspace, $\Phi$ and $\bar{\Phi}$ are (anti)chiral superfields and $V$ is a superfield associated with the gauge field. But I haven't seen anywhere how to construct this in terms of $\mathcal{N}=1$ superfields like in the introduction to this question.